# Wordpress running in iframe

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress website is running in iframe. I am unable to identify why is it running in an iframe. Any help would be highly appreciated. You can view the website at: http://www.fitnessschule.com

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to debug your site. To see actual problem need to review your code. if you have trust then you share your site credentials.

Comment: this is your actual site link where site is running : http://fitnessschule.com.lorca.ch-meta.net/, your developer just loaded this site in a iframe which is on different domain http://www.fitnessschule.com/  , this is total wrong...

Comment: Because your website developer is smarter if he sent you a website place on http://fitnessschule.com.lorca.ch-meta.net/ and just call that website in this http://www.fitnessschule.com website. If he remove a webiste from original your website will be down.

Comment: The Wordpress is not being installed my developer. This is me who installed it. I can't figure out why is it running in the iframe. I just need a guidance from you guys that which files should I look into to get it out of iframe. It should run without iframe at http://www.fitnessschule.com and not at fitnessschule.com.lorca.ch-meta.net.